# How get element from json on php?

Tags: php

When I use `var_dump($_POST)`, I get this:

```
array(2) {
  ["param"]=>
  string(327) "{"username":"asd","password":"asdasd","language":"7"}"
}
```

I need to get `username`. I've tried it this:

```
$arr = json_decode($_POST['param'], true);
echo $arr["username"];
```

But it doesn't work.

Anyone know where my error is and what the right way to get element `username` is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the edited answer:

```
$arr = json_decode($_POST['param'],true);
echo $arr['username'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jason encoded string seems to be inside the `param` element, Try this:

```
$arr = json_decode($par['param'], true);
echo $arr["username"];
```